# How to prevent nav elements from wrapping in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">`, wrapped within a container, and by design when the break point, marked by the end of the container is reached, it wraps around to a new line. How can I prevent this from happening so that everything stays inline and I can scroll horizontally instead?

Edit: Included code

```
<div class="jumbotron border">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Placeholder for image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post *all* of the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`flex-nowrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#wrap) class for the list. Use `d-flex` also if the `ul` is not already `flex`,

Comment: The `flex` classes worked! Thank you, in my case the lists were still going over the container so I had to include an `overflow` attribute